# How to extract 3D rainfall netCDF data

Tags: python, netcdf

this is my first time using python (anaconda spyder) to extract rainfall netCDF data i've got from NASA website. the code i write based on my lecture :

```
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = "C:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/g4.timeAvgMap.GPM_3IMERGDF_06_precipitationCal.20000601-20210930.110E_7S_110E_7S.nc"
d = xr.open_dataset(f)

variable = d['GPM_3IMERGDF_06_precipitationCal']

variable.plot()
plt.title('title')
plt.xlabel('Lable x')
plt.ylabel('Lable y')
plt.show()

print(d['GPM_3IMERGDF_06_precipitationCal'])

df = d['GPM_3IMERGDF_06_precipitationCal'].to_dataframe()
print(df)

df.to_excel('C:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/convertdata2.xlsx')
```

However, i realize the coordinates in netCDF file is only longitude and lattitude, but the attributes there is start time and end time like i'm desired downloaded from NASA website.
[image: variable and attribute]

the result i got is still in raw 2D :

[image: Result],
[image: Result]
[image: Result]

with those syntax i only extract the 2D data of longitude and lattitude with 3rd Dimensional data of time still accumulated.

my question is how to extract for specific longitude and lattitude into time series data ? and is it possible ? or the data is just the way it is and i should do another method like downscalling in other apps or syntax. my objective is to having specific longitude and lattitude and the extracted data are : precipitation and date/time from start date to end date like this (this just example, date:time | rainfall) :

[image: expected result]

Thanks in advance for the help.

the netCDF file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/15TsFO9zseezADIPiubba5q7-qyPyZgSg/view?usp=share_link